# Xamarin Forms Scrollview with xaml views & dynamic content

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Forms, how do I get a page with scroll view containing Some xaml view & dynamic list.

Here's a sample on what I want.

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Vertical">  <!-- TO MAKE WHOLE PAGE SCROLLABLE -->
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

                <!-- SOME XAML VIEWS HERE-->
                <Frame Margin="8">
                   ###############
                </Frame>

                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                    ################
                    <!-- A DYNAMIC LIST HERE Just like ListView but with dynamic data and without scroll,
                         just like linear layout in android-->
                </StackLayout>

            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[Bindable Layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts)** to achieve that .

The appearance of each item in the bindable layout can be defined by setting the `BindableLayout.ItemTemplate` attached property to a `DataTemplate`:

```
<ScrollView>
    ...
    <StackLayout x:Name="MyStackLayout" Orientation="Vertical">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="GreenYellow">
                    ...
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    ...
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </StackLayout>
    ...
</ScrollView>
```

The effect :

[image]